# PHP - get value from json object?

Tags: php, json, sms, vonage

How do i get the value of `message-id` from `json` object? When i do `$js->messages[0]->message-id` then i get `HTTP ERROR 500`

Curl data:

```
{
      "message-count": 1,
      "messages": [
        {
          "to": "447700900000",
          "message-id": "0A0000000123ABCD1",
          "status": "0",
          "remaining-balance": "3.14159265",
          "message-price": "0.03330000",
          "network": "12345"
        }
      ]
    }
```

PHP:

```
$js = json_decode($result);   
if ($js->messages[0]->status =="0") {
   $sms_status = 'success' . $js->messages[0]->message-id;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `-` is not a valid character for PHP variables.  Use this syntax:

```
$sms_status = 'success' . $js->messages[0]->{'message-id'};
```

Answer (score 0):

Or change `message-id` to `message_id`, like this

```
$json = '
{
      "message-count": 1,
      "messages": [
        {
          "to": "447700900000",
          "message_id": "0A0000000123ABCD1",
          "status": "0",
          "remaining-balance": "3.14159265",
          "message-price": "0.03330000",
          "network": "12345"
        }
      ]
    }
';

$js = json_decode($json);   
if ($js->messages[0]->status =="0") {
   $sms_status = 'success' . $js->messages[0]->message_id;
}

echo $sms_status;
```

Comment: Cant change message- into message_. Because its a third party API where i do not have modification option.